# query builder returns array instead of collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

User.php(User model)

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
  public function profiles(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
    }
}
```

Profile.php (Profile model)

```
class Profile extends Model
{
  public function users(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Function which returns data to view:

```
public function show_users(){
    $users = User::where('id','!=',Auth::user()->id)->get();
    return view('pages.show_users')->withUsers($users);
}
```

show_user.blade.php(View)

```
@foreach($users as $user)
   {{$user->profile->first_name}} //Gives error:Trying to get property of non-object
   {{$user->profiles['first_name']}} // Gives desired result
@endforeach
```

Why the result is returned in array instead of collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you are getting that error is beacause

Some users might not have a profile. so calling first_name on profile which is a null object will throw an error.

What you can is on **php7** you can do

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    {{$user->profiles->first_name ?? 'No first name'}}
@endforeach
```

php 5.6 and below

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    @if($user->profiles->isNotEmpty())
       {{$user->profiles->first_name}}
    @else
       No name
    @endif
@endforeach
```

And moreover why don't use eager loading to load your profiles for performance benefit. Your query now will create the N+1 query problem.

You can change your query to

```
public function show_users()
{
   $users = User::with('profiles')->where('id','!=',Auth::user()->id)->get();
   return view('pages.show_users')->withUsers($users);
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I was trying your solution bt I got some error. I ve created a trait and included in User module and access methods inside trait by following

Route::get('/show_user',function(){
   return Auth::user()->show_users();
});

I get an error: Call to a member function show_users() on null when I changed old function with one provided by you. Can u suggest something?

Comment: You are welcome. Can you accept it as the right answer

Comment: sure. I would like to know about following in more detail
 $users = User::with('profiles')->where('id','!=',Auth::user()->id)->get();
How it helps in retrieving records? is there any documentation for this.

Comment: Sure. Check this. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Answer (score 1):

The result returned is indeed a collection. It is just a typo issue

You forget an `s` here in `profiles`

```
{{ $user->profiles->first_name }}
```

Also please note that even if you access `first_name` as such

```
{{ $user->profiles['first_name'] }}
```

It doesn't mean it is not a collection.

If you check the source of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php`, you will see that it implements some cool functions such as `offsetGet`, `offsetSet`, and `offsetExists`

More information here. [PHP ArrayAccess](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php)

Comment: sry for typo but {{$user->profiles->first_name}} gives the same error and thank you for the info

Comment: {{ $user->profiles['first_name'] }} gives empty data too even though I have not any of such record in my database tables